# How to get consumer metrics using kafka admin client?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to write an API to display consumer metrics in java. I thought of using Kafka admin client. Is there any way we can retrieve consumer metrics information

I checked admin client code. I have Kafka consumer class. I have consumer metrics method, but it is not holding the information.

Comment: what type of metrics you need?

Comment: Admin client only talks to the brokers, not the consumer clients

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring

Answer (score 1):

Kafka consumer can report a lot of [metrics through JMX](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumer_monitoring), you just need to add a few Java properties to your consumer, either in the code or through command-line. For example, for console consumer:

```
$ KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9398 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"  kafka-console-consumer ...
```